# what will be wp-config file settings for mysql master and slave platform

Tags: database, wordpress, load-balancing, centos7, master-slave

I have database  on master-slave platform  and WordPress website using cloudflare  load balancer, so what  will be  DB-HOST config settings for wordpress website on both  the servers?

I have tried with DB-HOST as my master  server IP , but it is duplicating records on master  server.

I want records should be  added to master and   replicated to slave  so I am  not getting what should I add  at wp-config file for DB_HOST for such set up.